# Attempting to Make Quiz Application. How can I temporarily automatically store combo-box values in a database

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

thank for viewing my post.  Recently I have been working on a quiz application but as part of it after you hit a button called "take a quiz" a new form loads that shows three combo-boxes stuff for all the fields you need. (class, Teacher Subject).  But then when the new form loads after hitting next how can I have those values stored in someway so then you select the quiz and it loads.

Note: This is not a webpage but rather a desktop application.
1.  How can I temporarily store combo box values (I am flexible if I need a database then I will use one)

2. How can I make the combo boxes eliminate options for the ones below it as you select fields

eg:

```
Teacher        ComboBox1(values: Teacher 1, Teacher 2)
Class          ComboBox2(values: Class 3, Class 6)
Subject        ComboBox3(values: Math, Language Arts)
```

Comment: What's the framework of your application? web? windows or Mobile?

Comment: C# Desktop Application, sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: how many total temporary combo box you want to store?

Comment: Not terribly to many  maybe 100 in all the combo boxes

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** Assuming that you do not have to store so many temporary values, you can store the values in application settings and access them globally.

Click on your Project -> Properties -> Settings

[image]

Now fill name just like a variable -> Select Type (probably string in your case) -> Select Scope (User in your case) -> store initial value, you can also store a blank string.

Now to use these in your code, you can do this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Admin = "S"; // sets the value of string Admin in app settings to "S"
Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); // saves the new value in the app settings

string admin = Properties.Settings.Default.Admin; // assigns the value of Admin in the app settings to string admin.
```

**2.)** You will have to use `SelectedValueChanged` event of the ComboBox. Use the code below to delete the other choice as the user selects a choice.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
}

void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Teacher 1")
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Remove("Teacher 2");
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Remove("Teacher 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then select it as answer :P

Answer (score -1):

1: i'm not sure what you want; please explain the "flow" you are expecting

2: use javascript; you can dynamically change html content, check an example here
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/2levelcombo.shtml